# Dandelion DataTable Theamleaf - Pagination loosed

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, dandelion

I'm using Dandelion DataTable component in version 1.1.0, Thymeleaf and Spring MVC

I can filter the table with number of data and i can use the pagination.

I've problem with this scenario :

- I click in one line of data and i show its detail in new page
- I return to the DataTable (previous page), and here, i loose the pagination and number of data (the state of datatable was not saved.

Here is the part of my code :

```
<table id="table_result" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" dt:table="true" dt:url="@{/accor/orders/search}" 
dt:sortable="true" dt:pagingType="full_numbers"
dt:lengthMenu="'10,25,50,100'" dt:pageable="true" dt:info="true" dt:dom="lpirt" dt:theme="bootstrap2" dt:serverside="true" dt:processing="true" 
dt:ajaxParams="getExtraParams" dt:autowidth="false" dt:filterSelector="#filterButton">
```

How can i save the state of DataTable ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `StateSave` and `StateLoad` callback for this behavior.
There are examples in the [official documentation](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#7-3-1-available-callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the [attribute](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#opt-ajax.stateSave) `<table ... dt:statesave="true">` and it will store in your local storage the current state.

No need to write custom callbacks ;)